# Pull extra data out of Powerpoint Chart's spreadsheet

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint, cell

Aimed at all PowerPoint gurus.

If you have a series of data that is generating a chart in PowerPoint 
The data in excel would look like

1. Item1    10
2. Item2    20
3. Item3    30
4. Item4    40
5. Total    100

It is simple enough to pull the items through and show their value on the chart ... but what if you want to pull through the total value through as well? 
In other words have the value of that Cell (call it B5) show in a seperate text box?

you can target specific cell within the Cell labels by using the [cell] syntax but that only works within the label... and you cannot duplicate a label for a cell/series.

is there a simple way to reference the table from which the chart is created and pull the value of a specific cell ?

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oCht As Chart
Dim oChtData As ChartData
Dim x As Long

' For purposes of example, assume that we've got a chart in PPT
' and that it's selected:
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
' We could as easily pass a reference to the shape to this routine as a param

' Sanity test; if it's not a chart, bug out
If Not oSh.HasChart Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set oCht = oSh.Chart
    Set oChtData = oCht.ChartData
End If

With oChtData
    .Activate
    Debug.Print .Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2)
End With

' This leaves the workbook open , so:
oChtData.Workbook.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

.pptx files can be unzipped to reveal the embedded .xlsx files for each chart. Why don't you try this approach to get to the data you seek. Just change the extension of the file to .zip, extract and unleash the juicy goodness inside. You will find the Excel spreadsheet in there that comes up when you edit the data for the chart in PowerPoint.

There are a dozen different ways to access .xlsx data, depending on what technology stack you are using (google that separately). You can then interrogate the cells and sheets as you want. The coolest part is that editing the data in this fashion and rezipping the pptx gives you a great way to build automated reports using PowerPoint as your output... animations and all.

BTW, this same technique of unzipping, modifying and rezipping a pptx is great for swapping out images in an automated fashion. You can then produce some images using another external system and then update the pptx from the command line.